# Best way to ID an Android Device

Tags: android

I have 10 devices that all have the same Android ID. Whoever set these devices up must have copied over the id when installing the operating system. The application i've created is using the Android ID to distinguish between devices.

Is there a way for me to change the id using my application?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't wrote more details I just guess that you talk about gingerbread devices. To that time there was a bug which ended in that many devices had the same ID.

Check also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2785485/995926) about Android IDs.

Comment: If you are doing something related to licenses better bind that to a Google account.